# Ionic where to put header and top navbar in ion-view?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to put header and top navbar inside of the ion-view directive.

If I put header nav navbar outside of the `ion-view` tag page is blinking black if page is initialized.

But if I try to insert header and top navbar inside of the `ion-view` title and heading in the header is not displayed.

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Maybe some tag inside is missing?

Thanks for any help.

**Here is the code of the template:**

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-positive has-tabs-top">
    <button class="button button-icon icon  ion-chevron-left" ui-sref="home">
    </button>
    <h1 class="title">{{ 'RESULTS_BY_DAY' | translate }}</h1>
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-stats-bars" ui-sref="daily-chart">
    </button>
</div>

<!--TOP TAB BAR -->
<div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-light tabs-light tabs-color-dark">
    <div class="tabs">
      <a class="tab-item orange">
        Home
      </a>
      <a class="tab-item">
        Favorites
      </a>
      <a class="tab-item">
        Settings
      </a>
    </div>
</div>

<ion-view>
<div class="bar bar-header bar-positive has-tabs-top">
    <button class="button button-icon icon  ion-chevron-left" ui-sref="home">
    </button>
    <h1 class="title">{{ 'RESULTS_BY_DAY' | translate }}</h1>
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-stats-bars" ui-sref="daily-chart">
    </button>
</div>

<!--TOP TAB BAR -->
<div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-light tabs-light tabs-color-dark">
    <div class="tabs">
      <a class="tab-item orange">
        Home
      </a>
      <a class="tab-item">
        Favorites
      </a>
      <a class="tab-item">
        Settings
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
  <ion-content  ng-controller="DailyListCtrl">

      <!--WRITEOUT OVERAL STATS FOR DAYS -->
      <ion-list class="list" >
          <ion-item class="item itemListCustom" ng-repeat="listDataItem in listData">

                  <div class="listDateTimeBlock">
                    <div class="day"><h3>{{listDataItem.DATE_FROM_DD}}</h3></div>
                    <div class="month"><h3>{{listDataItem.DATE_FROM_MM}}</h3></div>
                  </div>

                <!--ROW ONE -->                  
                <div id="left">
                    <div class="left-inner">
                        {{ 'APPOINTMENT_SUCCESS_RATE' | translate }}:
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-inner">
                        {{listDataItem.SUCCESS_RATE}} %
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                    <div class="left-inner floatRight">
                        {{ 'DIALS' | translate }}:
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-inner">
                         {{listDataItem.DIALS_CNT}}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--ROW TWO-->
                <div id="left">
                    <div class="left-inner ">
                        {{ 'SUCCESS_RATE_SINCE_START' | translate }}:
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-inner">
                        {{listDataItem.SUCCESS_RATE_SINCE}} %
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                    <div class="left-inner floatRight">
                        {{ 'CONVERSATIONS' | translate }} :
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-inner">
                         {{listDataItem.CONVERS_CNT}}
                    </div>
                </div>                  

                <!--ROW THREE-->
                <div id="left">
                    <div class="left-inner">
                        {{ 'MY_DEFICIT' | translate }}:
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-inner">
                        {{listDataItem.DEFICIT}} %
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                    <div class="left-inner floatRight">
                       {{ 'APPOINTMENTS' | translate }} :
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-inner">
                       {{listDataItem.APPT_CNT}}
                    </div>
                </div>                  
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

   <ion-infinite-scroll
      icon="ion-loading-c"
      distance="30%"
      on-infinite="setDateRange();">
    </ion-infinite-scroll>

  </ion-content>

  <!-- BOTTOM TABS -->
     <div class="tabs-striped tabs-background-positive tabs-light">
    <div class="tabs">
      <a class="tab-item active" ui-sref="daily-list" href="/#/daily-list">
        <i class="icon ion-ios7-paper-outline"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="weekly-list" href="/#/weekly-list">
        <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="daily-list" href="/#/daily-list">
        <i class="icon ion-gear-a"></i>
      </a>
       <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="daily-list" href="/#/daily-list">
        <i class="icon ion-gear-a"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I click +1 because just reading your code I learned how to put in the top of the page the tabs: just adding the class 'tabs-top'. Thank you!

Comment: hi .. (it"s a suggestion) for design realted things in ionic use this link [**Use this link**](https://creator.ionic.io/app/login) ionic has it own theme bulider this would help you to start a deisgn temaplate

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 6):

Here are some examples of navbar usage:

- Simple page with buttons left and right:

http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/YwLELa

```
  <ion-view title="onepage">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      <button class="button">
        LeftButton
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>        
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
      <button class="button button-assertive">
        RightButton
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>        

    <ion-content class="padding">
      <!-- The content of the page -->
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

- Navigation via side menu:

http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/XXBvYp

- Navigation via side menu and tab bar:

http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/xZWXBO

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the JavaScript versions of [tabs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/) and [navigation bars](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBar/).
They are easier to be manipulated in JS code, because they come with the services `$ionicTabsDelegate` and `$ionicNavBarDelegate`.

Comment: That might solve achieve the same goal, but it is not an answer to the question and I'm facing the exact same issue.

Is it possible to add buttons to the `nav-view` header bar? Should it support `ion-header-bar` or not? If it should then it is not working, at least for me.

Comment: I have the same issue and didn't find a solution so far.

Comment: me too...pulling my hairs for the same issue here. I have a top header and then below that have 2 panes, the left-side bar and a right side main pane content area. Then I have a sub header for main pane.Under this sub-header, I want to show a nav-bar or tabs, but neither appears wherever I place it - above the ion-nav-view or  in  ion-view - outside or inside of ion-content. Why doesn't the nav-bar simply gets to the top of its containing div.